# How to save addresses from bounced messages in Exim 4?

Tags: email, smtp, exim, email-bounces, email-server

I need to save all bounces in a database, so I can query it from my application and not mail to any address that bounced more than X times.

If I recall correctly, Postfix allows to pipe messages to shell commands, so I was thinking that maybe Exim could have something similar, but any other easier/simpler option will do, as long as the data gets stored.

Any ideas?

A detailed explanation would be much appreciated, since I'm not a sysadmin and only dealt with MTAs very briefly in the distant past.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good idea; I wish all bulk mailers would do that!

Exim does have a way of doing this. However, you really need to read the documentation thoroughly - cargo-culting off of an answer given by a random stranger on the internet is highly likely to give you problems later on...

The basic way to do this is to set up a .forward file for that address. The contents should look something like

```
# Exim filter

pipe /path/to/program-that-stores-in-database
```

But there is a lot more that can be done, and if you're the one to manage this server, set aside an hour to read through the documentation at [exim.org](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html). It will more than pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Jenny! I was looking for something like that but couldn't find it (no wonder; it was 2:30am :) ).

I did look at the documentation but it's been a long time since I touched an MTA's configuration and then I used mostly Postfix, so Exim is a bit alien to me.

I'm not the one configuring the server, I'm just trying to help, but I agree about just randomly/blindly following instructions.

Comment: Exim is a fairly complex mailserver to setup, with lots of options, so I understand that it's not easy to just jump in and find the right option immediately, even for someone who's been running other MTAs recently.

Comment: So I came up with this:  

    # Exim filter
    
    if error_message then
        pipe /path/to/program-that-stores-in-database
        finish
    endif

For some reason, block indenting (start a line with four spaces) doesn't seem to be working here, neither do line breaks (ending a line with two spaces). Sorry about that.

Comment: Indentation doesn't work in comment, just in questions/answers.

Comment: That explains it. Althouth the "Learn more" link in the help does mention indented blocks and line breaks. Oh well. Thanks again, Jenny.